# Android Custom Keyboard - How to get browsers InputType?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to make a custom Android Keyboard (min API 16) with keyboard for every Input Type (like simple text, numeric, email, URL address, etc). The thing I don't get it is how to get the browsers URL TextEditor InputType so I can make a keyboard with 'Access' button.

```
@Override public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);

    switch (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:
            mCurKeyboard = symKeyboard_1;
            break;
        case InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI:
        case InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT:
        case InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
        case InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT:
        case InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS:
        case InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
            mCurKeyboard = webKeyboard;
            Log.d("debug", "web keyboard");
            break;
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
            mCurKeyboard = myKeyboard;
            Log.d("debug", "text");
            break;
        default:
            mCurKeyboard = myKeyboard;
            Log.d("debug", "default");
            break;
    }
}
```

But I still get as InputType the `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`.

I think I've tried almost all the `InputType` but none works to determine when I'm typing in the URLs text box. I need a solution to find the Input Type of URL TextEditor.

BTW: How do I perform an `Access` or `Go` action to browser, through a `KeyEvent` passed to `getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent()`  ?

**Later Edit. Solution:**

```
@Override public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);

    switch (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:
            currentKeyboard = numericKeyboard;
            break;
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
            int webInputType = attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION;

            if (webInputType == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI ||
                    webInputType == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT ||
                    webInputType == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
                    || webInputType == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS) {
                currentKeyboard = webKeyboard;
            }else{
                currentKeyboard = latinKeyboard;
            }
            break;
        default:
            currentKeyboard = latinKeyboard;
            break;
    }
}
```

@ray20 said the answer for handling the "Access", "GO" action, this is for other editor actions:

```
private void handleAction(){
    EditorInfo curEditor = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();
    switch (curEditor.imeOptions & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION){
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
            getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
            getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
            getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
            getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
            getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);
            break;
        default:
            handleClose(); //method that hides the keyboard with no action performed
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform GO action just

`getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);`